# How to skip one day for not leap years

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, amazon-redshift

I have generated a table that contains dates from 2000-01-01 to 2039-12-31 (ISO format). Calendar contains leap years. Now based on this I want to create another table with some transformations. I have a problem with two columns.

`Fiscal_year_day_nr` and `Fiscal_quarter_daynr`.

Each year has 366 days for `Fiscal_year_day_nr`, but for not leap years there is a skip of 29 Feb. So 28 Feb is the 59 day and 1 Mar is 61 day. For leap years there is a day nr 60 for 29 Feb.

How can I make it to skip that one day in not leap years? Lets say that table `calendar` contains one column named `date` with all the dates and based on this table new table is created with `date`, `Fiscal_year_day_nr` and `Fiscal_quarter_daynr`.

I am using Redshift SQL (RSQL).

Comment: I would combine `to_char()`, `to_timestamp()`, and `datediff()` to force the calculation to be done within a leap year regardless of the actual year for the date.

Comment: Someone likely went an extra mile to join on month and day to an example leap year to produce that "uniform" day numbering, for some reason. It's easier to skip that day, maintaining numbering continuity, than it is to introduce that gap. If you haven't already, I'd expect that at some point you'll stumble upon some legacy code that expects you to have that gap.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table calendar as with recursive g("date") as 
  (select '2000-01-01'::date union all select "date"+1 from g 
   where "date" <= '2039-12-31'::date) 
select "date" from g;
```

To maintain continuous numbering, you can use an [`extract()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html) and [`row_number()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) [window function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html), with your window definition based on [`date_trunc()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BWZrD6iV)

```sql
create table new_table as 
select "date", 
       extract(yearday from "date") as "Fiscal_year_day_nr",
       row_number()over(partition by date_trunc('year',"date"),
                                     date_trunc('quarter',"date")
                        order by "date") 
         as "Fiscal_quarter_daynr"
from calendar
order by "date";
```

| date | Fiscal_year_day_nr | Fiscal_quarter_daynr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-31 | *(non-leap year shorter)* 365 | 92 |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-02-28 | 59 | 59 |
| 2024-02-29 | *(leap year)* 60 | 60 |
| 2024-03-01 | 61 | 61 |
| 2024-03-31 | 91 | 91 |
| 2024-04-01 | 92 | 1 |
| 2025-02-28 | 59 | 59 |
| 2025-03-01 | *(no gap)* **60** | 60 |
| 2025-03-31 | 90 | 90 |
| 2025-04-01 | 91 | 1 |

If you ***do*** want to see that numbering gap on non-leap years, you can conditionally add the day when appropriate. Casting the condition `boolean` to `int` simplifies that:

```sql
create table calendar_skipping_feb29 as 
select "date",
       extract(yearday from "date")
          +(extract(month from date_trunc('year',"date")::date+59) = 3
            and 60<=extract(yearday from "date"))::int
          AS "Fiscal_year_day_nr",
       row_number()over(partition by date_trunc('year',"date"),
                                     date_trunc('quarter',"date")
                        order by "date")
          +(extract(month from date_trunc('year',"date")::date+59) = 3
            and 60<=extract(yearday from "date") 
            and 1 =extract(quarter from "date"))::int
          AS "Fiscal_quarter_daynr"
from calendar;
```

If the 60th day of the year (Jan 1st `+59` days) is in March (month `3`), it's a non-leap year, so from the 60th day onwards, you'll have `1` added to `"Fiscal_year_day_nr"` (`true` cast to `int` is `1`). `"Fiscal_quarter_daynr"` does the same, but only in the 1st quarter.

| date | Fiscal_year_day_nr | Fiscal_quarter_daynr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-31 | *(gap-added non-leap year)* **366** | 92 |
| 2024-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-02-28 | 59 | 59 |
| 2024-02-29 | *(leap year unaffected)* 60 | 60 |
| 2024-03-01 | 61 | 61 |
| 2024-03-31 | 91 | 91 |
| 2024-04-01 | 92 | 1 |
| 2025-02-28 | 59 | 59 |
| 2025-03-01 | *(gap added)* **61** | 61 |
| 2025-03-31 | 91 | 91 |
| 2025-04-01 | 92 | 1 |

Answer (score -1):

Elegance is nice, but never under estimate the power of brute force. You can achieve what your looking for with only standard Postgres provided [date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/functions-datetime.html), even those from version 8 (which is the base of Redshift) and a little helper function. (see demo)

```
create or replace function is_leap_year(year_in integer)
  returns boolean
 language plpgsql
 immutable
as $$
declare 
    lvar date; 
begin
    lvar = make_date(year_in,02,29); 
    return true; 
exception 
    when others then
        return false;
end;
$$;

with std_calendar(gregorian_dt) as 
     ( select generate_series('2000-01-01'::date 
                             ,'2004-03-01'::date
                             ,interval '1 day'
                             )::date
      ) --select * from std_calendar
insert into fy_table(gre_date
                    ,fiscal_year_day_nr
                    ,fiscal_quarter
                    ,fiscal_quarter_daynr
                    )   
    select gregorian_dt::date
         , extract(doy from gregorian_dt)
               + case when not is_leap_year(extract(year from gregorian_dt)::integer)
                       and extract(month from gregorian_dt) > 2 
                      then 1
                      else 0
                 end fydn 
       , extract(quarter from gregorian_dt) fg 
       , extract( days from (gregorian_dt - date_trunc('quarter', gregorian_dt))) + 1
             + case when not is_leap_year(extract(year from gregorian_dt)::integer)
                     and extract(month from gregorian_dt) > 2 
                    then 1
                    else 0
               end fqdnr
  from std_calendar;
```

You did not define your fiscal year so demo assumes it corresponds to calendar year and you want the same skip day functionality.